# VMware Fusion and MacbookPro keyboard

Tags: windows-7, vmware, keyboard-layout, vmware-fusion

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate (retail) under VMware Fusion on a Macbook Pro.  I've created a keyboard layout for the mac using Microsoft keyboard Layout Creator [MSKLC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FB7B3DCD-D4C1-4943-9C74-D8DF57EF19D7&displaylang=en).

My problem is that when I type the quote or double quote character, nothing happens.  Then I press it again and get the character twice.  Similar behaviour also occurs when I use a standard US-International keyboard layout.

1. First press of **'** I get nothing.
2. Second press of **'** I get **''**

If I press **'** once, then press any other key it generally produces the expected output, e.g.

1. First press of **'** I get nothing
2. Now press **f** and I get **'f**

If I press **'** once, then press **i**, I get **í** (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ed/index.htm))

Interestingly, if I press **'** once, then press backspace it's as if I never pressed **'** (backspace functions normally).

A similar thing happens with **#**.

As you can imagine, it's taken me ages to type this out, with the keyboard doing what it's doing... should have flicked over to OSX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I know the reason:

You have mapped them to be **dead keys**.

A dead key, is a key to combine other key strokes to get a combined output. It exactly does what you described: when pressed once, nothing happens; when pressed twice, or pressed once plus space key, it repeats itself. If you press some letters, it gets you a combined output, like `á`.

Check your MSKLC mapping. Here is a good guide to follow:

http://www.angelfire.com/planet/linguisticsisfun/Creating_a_Keyboard_Using_MSKLC.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Check your keyboard layout settings in Windows 7.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you be more specific.  I am in the Win7 VM, and the layout seems correct, but the behaviour is odd as described. Even with a 'stock' US keyboard keyboard layout the same problems appear.

Comment: Something is with your keyboard layout. Key ' is binned to specific keyboard action. For example, when i am using Latvian layout key ' is for specific Latvian characters, while pressing it, i can type letters like ō, ā, ī, ķ, which cannot be find on standard keyboard. Consider to check your layout, which is set to be specific for specific language.